# Как обойти AuthKeyDuplicatedError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

Делаю скрипт,который работает в многопотоке с множество аккаунтами телеграмма через библеотеку **telethon**,но перенося свой проект на удаленный сервер стала возникать ошибка **AuthKeyDuplicatedError**
Как ее правильно обходить?

```
try:
    # await client.connect()
    # if (await client.get_me())==None:
    await client.start(phone=client.number,password=client.password)
    #await client.start(phone=client.number,password=client.password)
except errors.PhoneNumberBannedError as e:
    
    await client.logs_out()
    with lock:
        db.delete_account(id=client.id)
except errors.ApiIdInvalidError as e:
    
    console.error(f"Account {client.number} ApiIdInvalidError")
    print(client.number,client.session.filename)
    await client.logs_out()
    with lock:
        db.delete_account(id=client.id)

except errors.AuthKeyDuplicatedError as e:
   await client.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка исходит от Telegram, и Telethon мало что может сделать, чтобы ее обойти. Вы можете только попытаться на 100% убедиться, что ключ используется только под одним IP-адресом за раз.
Под ключом подразумевается auth key

Comment: Вы имеете в виде auth_key?